How to enable AUTOPROTECT for a SQL Server instance in an Azure SQL SqlVirtualMachines via a REST API call?
I am trying to enable autoprotect for a SQL Server instance on an Azure virtual machine. I want to do this using a REST call to the Azure API.
AUTOPROTECT is disabled
I'm using the AzureWorkloadSQLAutoProtectionIntent object and have followed Microsoft Azure's documentation regarding this object.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/protected-items/create-or-update?view=rest-backup-2024-04-01&tabs=HTTP#azurevmworkloadsqldatabaseprotecteditem
I have written the following PowerShell script, but it is not working:
$url = "https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/$vaultName/backupFabrics/Azure/backupProtectionIntent/$intentObjectName`?api-version=$apiVersion"

# Create Headers
$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Request Body
$parentID = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/SqlVirtualMachines/$serverName"

$body = @{
  "properties" = @{
      "backupManagementType" = "AzureWorkload";
      "itemId" = $itemId;
      "policyId" = $policyId;    
      "protectionIntentItemType" = "AzureWorkloadSQLAutoProtectionIntent";
      "sourceResourceId" = $parentID; 
      "workloadItemType" = "SQLDataBase";
  }
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Invoke Rest Method
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body $body

When I try to run this script, I get the following error:

Error:
"code": "BMSUserErrorInvalidInput",
"message": "Input provided for the call is invalid. Please check the required inputs"

I've double-checked all my resource IDs and am using the latest version of the API. Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong in this script? What are the correct steps to enable AzureWorkloadSQLAutoProtectionIntent for a SQL Server instance using a REST call to the Azure API?
Thank you in advance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/protection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-backup-protection-check-vm
Can you check this

I want to do that using rest-api, not via cli.

I was able to make it work. My backup container name was missing the 'VMAppContainer' value:

Wrong: Compute;<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>;<YOUR_VM_NAME>
Right: VMAppContainer;Compute;<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>;<YOUR_VM_NAME>

You can find the container using the following documentation:
→ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/protection-containers/get?view=rest-backup-2024-04-01&tabs=HTTP
Here is my final code:
# Constants
$subscriptionId = "<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
$resourceGroupName = "<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
$vaultName = "<YOUR_VAULT_NAME>"
$policyId = "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/<YOUR_VAULT_NAME>/backupPolicies/<YOUR_POLICY_NAME>"
$itemId = "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/<YOUR_VAULT_NAME>/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/<YOUR_CONTAINER_INFO>/protectableItems/<YOUR_PROTECTABLE_ITEM>"
$parentName = "/subscriptions/<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/<YOUR_VAULT_NAME>/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/<YOUR_CONTAINER_INFO>"
$intentObjectName = "<YOUR_INTENT_OBJECT_NAME>"
$apiVersion = "2022-01-01"
$url = "https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/$vaultName/backupFabrics/Azure/backupProtectionIntent/$intentObjectName?api-version=$apiVersion"

# Create Headers
$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Request Body
$body = @{
  "properties" = @{
    "protectionIntentItemType" = "RecoveryServiceVaultItem"
    "backupManagementType" = "AzureWorkload"
    "parentName" = $parentName
    "itemId" = $itemId
    "policyId" = $policyId
  }
} | ConvertTo-Json 

# Invoke REST Method
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body $body


ERROR:

Error: "code": "BMSUserErrorInvalidInput", "message": "Input provided for the call is invalid. Please check the required inputs"

The error BMSUserErrorInvalidInput indicates that one of the parameters is incorrect or missing.
Check if  all resource IDs, like subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, vaultName, serverName, itemId, and policyId, are correct.
The below is the code to call the REST to enable automatic protection:
PUT https://management.azure.com/Subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/{vaultName}/backupFabrics/Azure/backupProtectionIntent/{intentObjectName}?api-version=2024-04-01
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}

{
  "properties": {
    "backupManagementType": "AzureWorkload",
    "itemId": "{itemId}",
    "policyId": "{policyId}",
    "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureWorkloadSQLAutoProtectionIntent",
    "sourceResourceId": "{parentID}",
    "workloadItemType": "SQLDataBase"
  }
}


I still got the same error
